# Which headers in the C++ standard library are guaranteed to include another header?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, header-files, c++20

The C++ standard library headers may include each other in unspecified ways, so programmers generally shouldn't depend on one header including another. In a few cases, however, a header is guaranteed to include another header, or make available certain functions that would otherwise require inclusion of another header. What are those cases?

Comment: Why is this information useful?

Comment: @Pradhan It's useful to know, for instance, that if you included `<vector>` you don't have to include `<initializer_list>`, or `<iterator>` if you just need `std::begin`/`std::end`.

Comment: @T.C. But it is a bad idea to not to specify explicitly the header file in which a type that you use is declared. This will make the code more difficult to read even though it could make the compilation a little bit faster. Devs are not supposed to know the guaranteed includes. Well, for the case of std::begin, it is obvious, but for other cases, it may not.

Comment: Please *include what you use* at all times. There is only downsides to not do it even if it is just taking 30 seconds to explain to co-workers why you did it. It already took you more time explaining it than doing the right thing.

Comment: @screwnut, `initializer_list` is an exception, though, _if it's used implicitly_ (which is the vast majority of the cases). It so seamlessly blends into the syntax that it can be considered an internal implementation detail of the std containers, and including it explicitly kinda even feels like the _wrong_ thing from that point ot view. _(If you're implementing your own container that uses it explicitly, that's a different story -- include it there, of course.)_

Answer (score 41):

This answer ignores C headers - both the `<meow.h>` and `<cmeow>` ones. Of the C++ library headers (all references are to N4659):

`<initializer_list>` is guaranteed to be included by:

- `<utility>` (§23.2.1 [[utility.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/utility.syn))
- `<string>` (§24.3.1 [[string.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.syn))
- `<array>` (§26.3.2 [[array.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array.syn))
- `<deque>` (§26.3.3 [[deque.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/deque.syn))
- `<forward_list>` (§26.3.4 [[forward_list.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/forward_list.syn))
- `<list>` (§26.3.5 [[list.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/list.syn))
- `<vector>` (§26.3.6 [[vector.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.syn))
- `<map>` (§26.4.2 [[associative.map.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.map.syn))
- `<set>` (§26.4.3 [[associative.set.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.set.syn))
- `<unordered_map>` (§26.5.2 [[unord.map.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map.syn))
- `<unordered_set>` (§26.5.3 [[unord.set.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.set.syn))
- `<queue>` (§26.6.2 [[queue.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/queue.syn))
- `<stack>` (§26.6.3 [[stack.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stack.syn))
- `<algorithm>` (§28.2 [[algorithms.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms.syn))
- `<random>` (§29.6.2 [[rand.synopsis]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/rand.synopsis))
- `<valarray>` (§29.7.1 [[valarray.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/valarray.syn))
- `<regex>` (§31.4 [[re.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/re.syn))

`<iostream>` is guaranteed to include `<ios>`, `<streambuf>`, `<istream>`, and `<ostream>` (§30.4.1 [[iostream.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iostream.syn)).

`<ios>` is guaranteed to include `<iosfwd>` (§30.5.1 [[ios.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/ios.syn)).

`<bitset>` is guaranteed to include `<string>` and `<iosfwd>` (§23.9.1 [[bitset.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/bitset.syn)).

The free function templates `std::begin`, `std::end`, the C++14 `c-`, `r-`, and `cr-` versions, and the C++17 free function templates `std::size`, `std::empty` and `std::data` nominally reside in `<iterator>`, but are also available if any of the following headers is included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, `<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<string>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<unordered_set>`, and `<vector>` (§27.7 [[iterator.range]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iterator.range), §27.8 [[iterator.container]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iterator.container)).

When `<string_view>` is included, the `*begin` and `*end` functions, and the two generic `std::swap` overloads defined in [[utility.swap]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/utility.swap) (`swap(T&, T&)` and `swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N])`) are guaranteed to be available. `size/empty/data`, however, are not. (§24.4.1 [[string.view.synop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.view.synop)).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Only difference after comparing N3337 and N4140 is the lack of `std::cbegin` etc. in C++11. Most of this is in the synopsis for the respective headers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the mandatory includes for C++20, taken from [N4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf).

compare is included in:

- array
- chrono
- coroutine
- deque
- filesystem
- forward_list
- iterator
- list
- map
- memory
- optional
- queue
- ranges
- regex
- set
- stack
- string
- string_view
- system_error
- thread
- tuple
- typeindex
- unordered_map
- unordered_set
- utility
- variant
- vector

initializer_list is included in:

- algorithm
- array
- deque
- forward_list
- list
- map
- queue
- random
- ranges
- regex
- set
- stack
- string
- thread
- unordered_map
- unordered_set
- utility
- valarray
- vector

string is included in:

- bitset

iosfwd is included in:

- bitset
- ios

concepts is included in:

- iterator

iterator is included in:

- ranges

ios, streambuf, istream are included in:

- iostream

ostream is included in:

- iostream
- syncstream

cstdint is included in:

- cinttypes

Comment: About your last point with cinttypes and cstdint, the paper you linked (29.12.2) defines it exactly the opposite: cinttypes is not included by cstdint, but cstdint is included by cinttypes.