# Why do we need to include the <string> header file when std::string will suffice to initialize a string in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string a="hello";
    std::cout<< a;
}
```

The above code prints out "hello". Then, why do people insist upon including the `<string>` header file?

Comment: In **your** case, `<iostream>` includes `<string>`...

Comment: type "using namespace std;" before int main() . you dont need to type std::something again and again ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan That is considered bad practice in serious programs. Its okay for small homework style questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan That is not exactly a good advice. While it might be easier to type, it's not recommended to plop the entire std namespace in a global one.

Comment: @Comrade reason behind it please ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Galik provided a link :)

Comment: @comrade  thanks ...

Comment: [Which headers in the C++ standard library are guaranteed to include another header?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26614983/3953764)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no guarantee your code will work without `<string>`. That is the header `std::string` is defined in, so you must include it if you want your code to be portable.

Your code may work or appear to work because `<iostream>` directly or indirectly includes `<string>`.

Comment: In at least some implementations, `<iostream>` includes `basic_string` and its aliaces, but not additional string facilities, like `to_string` and `stoi`. Other implementation includes `basic_string`, but not its aliases, so declaring `basic_string<char>` will work, but `std::string` won't.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Wouldn't a forward-declaration for `std::basic_string` suffice for implementing that header?

Answer (score 3):

I think your compiler is just being nice to you. If you are using strings, you should `#include <string>`, whether or not your particular compiler lets you get away without it. Moreover, apparently `<iostream>` includes `<string>`, directly or indirectly, but *don't rely on it*.

Comment: "not supposed to ... `#include <string>`" - not so. Standard headers are allowed to include any other standard headers.

Comment: yes you are right @PeteBecker