# Code compiles with g++ 5.2.1 but not with g++ 4.9.3

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Why this code compiles using `g++ 5.2.1`, but fails with `g++ 4.9.3`?

```
//exception.h
class MyError: public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
        using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
// nothing else here
```

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "exception.h"

int main() {}
```

`5.2.1` compilation:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ 5.2.1
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ g++ main.o -o a.out
```

Compilation successfull.

`4.9.3` compilation:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ 4.9.3
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ g++ main.o -o a.out
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
exception.h:3:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
exception.h:5:14: error: ‘std::runtime_error’ has not been declared
using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
....
```

**Solution** is to add  `#include <stdexcept>` to `exception.h`

Now it works with both versions.

When I remove `#include <iostream>` from main.cpp, then compilation fails even with 5.2.1 version and `#include <stdexcept>` is required too.

Why this code works on `5.2.1` version without including [stdexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) header?

It's included in `iostream` on `5.2.1` version but not in `4.9.3` version? Reading [GCC changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) didn't help.

Comment: C++ only specifies what happens when you follow the rules (which say that you must include the correct header). C++ does not specify what happens when you *don't* follow the rules. C++ can therefore not answer your question, nor is the answer terribly enlightening. Just follow the fine rules.

Comment: I hoped there is some good reason I couldn't figure out. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library headers are allowed to include other headers, but there are no guarantees.

Back in the ancient days of g++ 4.0 and 4.1, you could pull in most of the standard library with just `#include <iostream>` and `#include <deque>`. But that stopped working in version 4.3 (or something like that).

In order for your code to be portable it should explicitly include all the required headers.

Comment: "but there are no guarantees" - with [a few exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614983/which-headers-in-the-c-standard-library-are-guaranteed-to-include-another-head).