# std::initializer_list, braced initialization and header

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

While reading about a different topic I came across a weird behaviour, at least to me.
This whole thought originated from the special interactions between `auto` and braces. If you write something like:

```
auto A = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

the compiler will deduce `A` to be a `std::initializer_list`. The weird thing is that a similar rule applies not only to `auto`, where there can be special reasons for it, but also to other things.
If you write the following:

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> Vector)
{
    // do something
}
```

you can't of course call it in this way:

```
f({ 1, 2, 3});
```

even though a `std::vector` can be braced initialized. However, if you substitute the `std::vector` with `std::initializer_list`, the call works and the compiler will properly deduce `int` as the type `T`. The more interesting thing is, however, that in the former case you need to `#include <vector>`, in the latter you don't need to `#include <initializer_list>`. This made me think and after a test I realized somehow `std::initializer_list` don't need its own header, so it is in some way part of the "base" features.

Moreover, for everything to make sense, `std::initializer_list` should be to standard objects in more or less the same way lambdas are to callable objects (in the strictest meaning, that is an object with a `operator()`). In other words, unnamed braced definitions should default to `std::initializer_list` just like lambdas are (mostly) unnamed callable objects.

Is this reasoning correct? Moreover, can this behaviour be changed and, if so, how?

UPDATE: the header for `initializer_list` was found to be included transitively from `iostream` (really weird). However, the question remains: why the call works for `std::initializer_list` and not for `std::vector`?

Comment: A program that uses an initializer list but does not include `<initializer_list>` header is ill-formed. For example, GCC complains: *cannot deduce type of initializer list because `std::initializer_list` was not found; include `<initializer_list>`.*

Comment: The issue with your function is that it's a template, and it deduces the template argument `T` as an `initializer_list`, which `vector` cannot hold. If you had simply `void f(std::vector<int> v)` then calling `f({1,2,3});` works fine. I remember Scott Myers talked a bit about `initializer_list` and its idiosyncratic interaction between `auto` and `vector but I'll have to see if I can dig it up

Comment: [c++11 - Which headers in the C++ standard library are guaranteed to include another header? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614983/which-headers-in-the-c-standard-library-are-guaranteed-to-include-another-head)

Answer (score 9):

It is ill-formed ([so it requires a diagnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685448/1708801)) to not include the `initializer_list` header if we use `std::initializer_list`. We can see this from [[dcl.init.list]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#2):

> ... The template std::initializer_list is not predefined; if the header <initializer_list> is
>   not included prior to a use of std::initializer_list — even an implicit use in which the type is not
>   named (9.1.7.4) — the program is ill-formed.

Mostly likely you are including the header transitively, which is well-formed but makes your code more fragile, so include what you use.

We can see from a live godbolt example that having no includes we obtain a diagnostic as required from [gcc/clang/MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/NDeq_v) e.g.:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'    
void foo( std::initializer_list<int>) {
          ^
```

and including either `<vector>` or `<iostream>` we [no longer obtain a diagnostic](https://godbolt.org/z/BfyrSX).

Why it does not deduce as you expect is covered by [[temp.deduct.type]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.6) which tells us this is a non-deduced context:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   ...
>   - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified ([temp.deduct.call]).>
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3});                 // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> — end example  ]
>   ...

also see [[temp.deduct.call]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1):

> ... Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type]) ...

Comment: That's a possibility, but the only header I included are iostream and the built-in one for the project in VS, which should not inlcude anything else transitively.

Comment: @AndreaBocco yup including `iostream` as well as `vector` does it, see [live godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/BfyrSX) ... if you comment out the includes you obtain a diagnostic

Comment: Yes, you are right about the header being included transitively. Still, the other "half" of the question remain: why doesn't work to pass a braced initializer to the function for a vector while it does work for a initializer_list?

Comment: @AndreaBocco apologies, it was not clear there were two questions, I updated to address that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably including the header transitively from `<vector>` or `<iostream>`, keep in mind that the standard [explicitly enforces a non-deduced context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#type-5.6) for the `std::vector` case

> [temp.deduct.type]/p5
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> ...
>
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified ([temp.deduct.call]).

Cfr. [cppreference ex.6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Answer (score 0):

The CPP online reference for [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector) shows that `<initializer_list>` is included in its header.

GCC's implementation of `<vector>` includes `<initializer_list>`. This is probably true of other implementations as well. This is the reason you did not have to include `<initializer_list>` separately.

Check out this source for GCC 4.6.2 which includes `<initializer_list>` in the `<vector>` header.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01069_source.html