# initializer_list, constructors and braced initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

While reading about different types of initialization, I stumbled upon one of the numerous weird interaction of `std::initializer_list` (previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924740/stdinitializer-list-braced-initialization-and-header)). It's apparently a simple topic, one of the first presented in C++ books when they present `std::vector`.

The point is, if you have one constructor that takes a (I guess only) `std::initializer_list`, when you brace initialize this constructor will be strongly prefered: in other words, `std::vector<int> NewVect{5, 10}` will create an object containing 5 and 10, not 5 element initialized to 10 (`std::vector<int> NewVect(5, 10)`).

A special behaviour takes place for `auto` brace initialization (`auto A={1,2,3}` will be deduced to be a `std::initializer_list<int>`). Now, I can't believe in C++ a particular treatment is accorded to specific objects, since to my knowledge header are only well written and useful code snippet. Moreover, those syntaxes don't work if you don't directly or indirectly `#include <initializer_list>`, even though my compiler, VS2017, prints a very special set of error pointing out that it needs that header to work (you can easily test this out with `auto`).

So, my question is, given for granted that this behaviour is the effect of code from the initiliazer list's header and my compiler is probably built to assume the use of STD, how is it implemented? Could I reroute this behaviour to never happen aside from explicit call (that is, `std::vector<int> NewVect{5, 10}` would be equivalent to `std::vector<int> NewVect(5, 10)` and you would need now to call `std::vector<int> NewVect{std::initializer_list<int>{5, 10}}`)? Would be possible to give this behaviour to other, user-built classes?

Comment: Related: [Why is the std::initializer_list constructor preferred when using a braced initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27144054/580083)

Answer (score 9):

> given for granted that this behaviour is the effect of code from the initiliazer list's header and my compiler is probably built to assume the use of STD, how is it implemented?

There is a special rule in the Standard that says something along the lines of: *"if you are using list-initialization (`{...}`) to construct an object, and the object has a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list`, that constructor is chosen **regardless** of overload resolution"*. This means that `std::initializer_list` constructors always have priority over others when using `{...}` initialization syntax.

---

> Could I reroute this behaviour to never happen aside from explicit call

In your classes, you can avoid using `std::initializer_list`. Then this behavior will never occur. You cannot change this for `std::` classes.

---

> Would be possible to give this behaviour to other, user-built classes?

Not with your desired syntax, as `std::initializer_list` is special. You can create your own `initializer_list` alternative, or use something like a *variadic template* constructor to force users to have an explicit syntax.

Comment: A link to relevant section from the current Standard draft: [over.ics.list](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list).