# Necessity of importing <ios> header file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, manipulators

I declared a float variable, say `a`, then I assigned 57.00 to it. When I wanted to print the 'a' using *cout* object, the stream seemed to print only 57 without the decimal point.

So, the solution to making the decimal point printed is adding *showpoint* manipulator after cout. Example: `cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << endl;`

The function *setprecision* here is used together with *fixed* to specify the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point. After googling for a while, I found that *showpoint* and *fixed* are a part of `<ios>` header file.

So, why don't we have to import this header? Without importing it, the code worked just fine.
And importing `<iostream>` is all I need to make these stream manipulators worked as intended.

Is `<ios>` header automatically imported whenever and wherever the `<iostream>` header is imported?

Comment: First hit on Google: " Including this header may automatically include other headers, such as <ios>, <streambuf>, <istream>, <ostream> and/or <iosfwd>." Note the "may" though, I'd still use the import, if just for code clarity.

Comment: For reference, see Cppreference's page for the [`<iostream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) standard library header. There, under the Includes section, you'll see that `<ios>` is included. The C++ standard guarantees that, see [`[iostream.syn]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.syn) in the current draft. See also this question: [Which headers in the C++ standard library are guaranteed to include another header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26614983/1458097)