# Why can I use `std::move` without `#include <utility>`?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, transitive-dependency

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move says that `std::move` is

> Defined in header <utility>

The C++ standard [agrees](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) (p. 556).

Still, this compiles in several compilers, including https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr1, ptr2;
    ptr2 = std::move(ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Why? Does `<memory>` include `<utility>`? Can I rely on that, or is that an implementation detail that may change any time?

Comment: I'd trust cppreference more than "works on my machine".

Comment: You cannot rely on this, include what you are required to.  here is a list of what is guaranteed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614983/which-headers-in-the-c-standard-library-are-guaranteed-to-include-another-head

Comment: Basically https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.headers#1.sentence-1.

Comment: *Why?* Implementation detail. *Does `<memory>` include `<utility>`?*  Compilers are allowed to do that, but not required to do that. *Can I rely on that, or is that an implementation detail that may change any time?*  The latter.  Doesn't compile on my machine, for what it's worth.