# Compiler Error: Expected Nested Name Specifier before typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++98, typename

In a template class with two instantiation types (`T` and `PT`) I currently have the following line for using a `const_iterator` for the class:

```
typedef typename std::vector< std::pair<T, PT> >::const_iterator const_iterator;
```

This works in a C++11/14 environment however when compiling in a C++98 environment (which may, unfortunately, be required for various reasons) I get the error shown in the title, `expected nested name specifier before typedef`.

Is there any way I can resolve this issue for old compilers?

EDIT: Here is the basic structure of my class,

```
template<typename T, typename PT> class MyClass {

private:

    std::vector< std::pair<T,PT> > dataWithPriorityVec;    

    //... various private methods...

public:

    typedef typename std::vector< std::pair<T,PT> >::const_iterator const_iterator;

    //... constructors and various public methods...

};
```

Comment: How does your "template class" look like ?

Comment: Show a minimal complete example.

Comment: Your example compiles cleanly in several compiler versions here (besides, missing `;` after `const_iterator`).

Comment: Are you including `<vector>` and `<utility>` before the class definition?

Comment: Sorry, added the semi-colon now - that was there in my code anyway. Yeah I'm including vector but not utility - is that required?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee that `<utility>` (required for `std::pair`) is included in any of the other standard headers. So the compiler you use for the C++98 build could require it to compile correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including `<vector>` and `<utility>` before the class definition?

You need to ["include what you use"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26611481/3747990) to avoid cross compilation issues.

There is no guarantee that `<utility>` (required for `std::pair`), or `<vector>` are included in any of the other standard headers. *As noted in the comments.*

So the compiler you use for the C++98 build could require it to compile correctly.